# Getting the Position of a score while excluding the zero/empty values

Tags: php, mysql, position, rank

I have two different codes for getting the position of a student's score in two subjects. From result columns '*maths*' and '*english*' containing the scores of different users.

*This is what the result for a user looks like*

**Subject     Score   Rank**

**English       5           7**

**Maths          0           1**

*While this what I hope to get:*

**Subject     Score   Rank**

**English       5           7**

**Maths          0**

Here are the codes I used

**FOR ENGLISH**

```
<?php $sql="SELECT roll, FIND_IN_SET( English, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( English
ORDER BY English DESC ) 
FROM result )
) AS rank
FROM result
WHERE roll = '$roll'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

echo $row['rank'] ?>
```

**FOR MATHS**

```
<?php $sql="SELECT roll, FIND_IN_SET( maths, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( maths
ORDER BY mathsDESC ) 
FROM result )
) AS rank
FROM result
WHERE roll = '$roll'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

echo $row['rank'] ?>
```

Comment: Would you be able to prepare a SQL Fiddle for us, so we can see you input data? Please also add your input data into the question, as a formatted block (you don't need <br> and &nbsp; here - just. use a code block, as per your SQL).

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php (your code is vulnerable and use deprecated functions)

Comment: ORDER BY English- eh?